# Scanner cannot be resolved

Tags: java

```
    File inputTXT = new File (fileName);

    try{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputTXT);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("");
    }
        while(in.hasNext()){
            String line = in.nextLine();
```

It says in can't be resolved.How am I going to fix this problem?

I've tried ignored try catch block, but this file scanner has to be in the try catch block

Comment: Are you _possibly_ missing an `import` statement?

Comment: Show us the whole code with the error message that pops up.

Comment: Don't just swallow the exception; at least print it out. Otherwise you'll never know if it's throwing an error.

Comment: Note> Scanner is declared inside your try statement. Therefore you cannot use it, think in the scenario where your try actually throws an exception and your Scanner in is never reached `in.nextLine()` would not be resolved. You can wrap it all inside the try catch or declare the variable before the try.

Comment: And for the Scanner to be resolved, this might be missing: `import java.util.Scanner;` at the top of your file (after package if any). If you use an IDE it helps with those errors and imports them or suggest what to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have issue about variable scope.You defined `in` variable in try catch block and then you used it in while loop.It should be like below:

```
    File inputTXT = new File (fileName);
    Scanner in=null;
    try{
     in = new Scanner(inputTXT);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("");
    }
        while(in.hasNext()){
            String line = in.nextLine();
```